# Database integration testing in client application using COM interface

Tags: c#, testing

## Intro

I am working in environment in which enterprise host application is calling client applications with implemented COM interface via ProgID. This is the way how programmers of host application allows to enhance application with plugins.

```
Host app <-> COM interface <-> Client app
```

Client app can use methods from provided COM interface.

One of that method is `RunSqlQuery(rawSqlQuery)`. It has possibilites to fully communicate with SQL within scope of logged-in user of host application (based on connection authentication type it could be Windows or SQL user).

In our client applications we are not using any other database context - we are fully depending on host provided methods for run queries/commands in raw SQL.

As our codebase is growing, I am more and more worried about project architecture, testability and maintenance - which all are close to zero. As always - project managers does not see the problem with it.

## Question

The biggest problem is, that I cannot find a way how to write database integration tests, because we are coupled with host application methods.

In repository or query object I am using it something like this (simplified):

```
public List<Entity> GetAll()
{
    var entities = new List<Entity>();

    var result = _host.RunSqlQuery("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM table");

    while (!result.End())
    {
        // adding to list

        result.Next();
    }

    return entities;
}
```

It is impossible to test it in this form, because:

1. I have no context
2. If I use my own context, I cannot use that methods, because first must start host application, that is a place, where COM interface methods are executing.

So what can I do? Make some higher layer and use strategy to choose host methods or .NET SQL client methods based on environment (normal/test)? I can not get it.

I must be prepared, that everything I am doing is only for testability. I can mock it, but as I said, I want to run integration tests for parts, where it is possible.

Comment: COM in .NET is implemented primarily through interfaces. You should be able to replace `_host` with a custom object that implements whatever interface `_host` provides so you can implement `RunSqlQuery` yourself (or selectively pass through calls, if you want to run an integration test on those). If `_host` is now declared as a concrete class rather than an interface, replace it with an interface.

Comment: It does make a sense. I need to implement all related host interfaces to fit same behaviours with my own code (e. g. use SqlClient). After that I can choose which one will be the source of data for CQRS/repositories. Please, move that comment as an answer, I will probably accept it.

Comment: However, I see now, that it violates the LSP - I cannot use polymorphism, but I can try some strategy for using it. Why? I need to pass `DbContext` to `RunSqlQuery()`, which is not present in base type. Or, Maybe I can create context directly in it, I am confused.

Comment: You could give your custom class a `DbContext` field that's injected through the constructor (and then swap out `_host` instances as needed), or else as a writable property and change it when needed. The code using `_host` doesn't need to know where it gets the context, as long as your code creating the host can set it up.

Comment: Again, good point, thank you. I need to try it, it looks fine. Please, as I wrote move your comment to answer, it is really helpful.

Comment: First integration test passed and it was done without breaking any existing code. So it is working as you described. Thank you!